# Only show objects in array that contain a specific string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I was trying to make something where you can type a string, and the js only shows the objects containing this string. For example, I type Address1 and it searches the address value of each one then shows it (here: it would be Name1). Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/76e40vqg/11/

**HTML**

```
<input>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var data = [{"image":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg","name":"Name1","address":"Address1","rate":"4.4"},
{"image":"http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/38247214-image.png","name":"Name2","address":"Address2","rate":"3.3"},
{"image":"http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg","name":"Name3","address":"Address3","rate":"3.3"}
];

var restoName = [], restoAddress = [], restoRate = [], restoImage= [];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){    
        restoName.push(data[i].name);
        restoAddress.push(data[i].address);
        restoRate.push(data[i].rate);
        restoImage.push(data[i].image);
}

for(i = 0; i < restoName.length; i++){
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "Image : <a href='" + restoImage[i] + "'><div class='thumb' style='background-image:" + 'url("' + restoImage[i] + '");' + "'></div></a><br>" + "Name : " + restoName[i] + "<br>" + "Address : " + restoAddress[i] + "<br>" + "Rate : " + restoRate[i] + "<br>" + i + "<br><hr>";
  }
```

I really tried many things but nothing is working, this is why I am asking here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store the details as separate arrays. Instead, use a structure similar to the data object returned.

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
    if (data[i].address.indexOf(searchedAddress) !== -1) { // Get searchedAddress from user
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += data[i].name;
    }
}
```

Edits on your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76e40vqg/17/

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please edit my jsfiddle so I can see how it works? Tx

Comment: It's not working when I type something, everything disappears

Comment: THIS is working LoL. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hmmm. Working on jsfiddle but not on ky project

Comment: i've made the plunker code as a demonstration. you'll need to use the snippet i provided in the answer. that is the main part

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution :

```js
var data = [{"image":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg","name":"Name1","address":"Address1","rate":"4.4"},
{"image":"http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/38247214-image.png","name":"Name2","address":"Address2","rate":"3.3"},
{"image":"http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg","name":"Name3","address":"Address3","rate":"3.3"}
];
document.getElementById('search').onkeyup = search;
var output = document.getElementById('output');


function search(event) {
  var value = event.target.value;
  
  output.innerHTML = '';
  
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    var found = false;
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(val) {
      if(item[val].indexOf(value) > -1) found = true;
    });
    
    if(found) {
      // ouput your data
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = item.name
      output.appendChild(div);
    }
  });
  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search" />

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. A very good solution, but @K3v1n 's one is shorter.

Comment: Yes but it only search in the address field, my search is on every data (address, name etc ...)